# Is there an equivalent of "for str in StringList do" in C++ Builder?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I want to know if there is an equivalent for Delphi

```
var 
   StringList: TStringList;
for str in StringList do
```

in C++ Builder.

Comment: Something like `std::vector<std::string> myStringList; for (auto str : myStringList) { ... }`. Hard to answer unless you say what  you are using for StringList

Comment: TStringList is a C++Builder and Delphi type. **So OP is using TStringList**, which contains System::String instances, not std::string instances.

Comment: FWIW, @IceFire correctly removed the c++ tag here. This is a C++Builder-specific question and it should not carry the *c++* (for **standard C++**) tag.

Comment: the c++ tag was present because I thought that C++ might have functionality that can replace the Delphi "for s in list". If I don't include c++ tag it means that I don't answer from c++ world. But I want that.  Anyway, C++ cannot operate on Delphi object, so indeed this is a 100% Embarcadero-world question :)

Comment: C++ can't have functionality for a Delphi/C++Builder specific type. Next time, such specific questions should be without the general C++ tag, as it thoroughly confuses standard C++ users that don't know C++Builder. I've seen this happening quite a few times before.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis - lesson learned :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per Embarcadero's DocWiki:

[C++ Iterator Support for Delphi Enumerable Types and Containers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/C%2B%2B_Iterator_Support_for_Delphi_Enumerable_Types_and_Containers)

> The following are guidelines that can be used as a rule of thumb for which iterators are available for a type.
>
> - If the type only has a `GetEnumerator()` method, you can use **Range-for and a limited set of read-only STL Algorithms**.
> - If the type has a subscript `operator[]`, you can use **Range-for and all the read-only STL Algorithms**.
> - ...
>
> ...
>
> `TRandomIterator::<T,E>`
>
> `TRandomIterator::<T,E>` is defined for **every RTL container that implements the integer subscript operator `E operator[ ](int)` and an integer `Count` property**.
>   ...
>
> `TEnumerableIterator<T>`
>
> `TEnumerableIterator::<T>` is defined for **every Delphi RTL container that implements the `GetEnumerator()` method**. The returned Enumerator Type must also support the `GetCurrent()` and `MoveNext()` methods. **This pattern is frequently used in RTL code, so it covers a good portion of containers**.
>   ...

`TStringList` satisfies the requirements for both `GetEnumerator()` and `operator[]`, and as such, at least in the [CLang-based compilers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Clang), you can do things like this:

```cpp
TStringList *StringList = ...;

for (auto str : StringList)
{
    ...
}

std::for_each(std::begin(StringList), std::end(StringList), ...);
```

This functionality was added in C++Builder 10.1 Berlin.

See [Using Delphi containers from C++](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/using-delphi-containers-from-c) for more details

Comment: I get "[bcc32 Error] E2141 Declaration syntax error" on the "for (auto str : StringList)" line. More exactly, the compiler puts the cursor on the semicolon. I have C++ 10.2 (Tokyo).

Comment: @Rigel that error message says you are using the old [BCC32](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/BCC32) ("classic" NON-Clang) compiler, which does not support C++11. You need to use one of the newer [Clang-based compilers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Clang-enhanced_C%2B%2B_Compilers) instead to use C++11.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike what the other answer says, **the compiler matters a lot**. Only C++Builder can use types in the *Visual Component Library*, which is written in Delphi (Object Pascal).

*TStringList* is one such a class. It is a container (with some extras) for *System::String* instances (i.e. not a *std::vector* containing *std::string* instances).

*TStringList* does not expose C++ iterators, so AFAIK, currently, your only choice is indexing:

```cpp
TStringList *list = new TStringList();
// fill list
for (int i = 0; i < list->Count; ++i)
{
    // ...
}
delete list;
```

You could of course use a *`std::vector<System::String>`*, but that would not give you the additional functionality of a *TStringList* (like the storage of associated objects -- e.g. bitmaps -- or the special handling of *key=value* strings, etc.) .

#### Update

I must have done something wrong. As Remy Lebeau noted, this is in fact possible:

```cpp
TStringList *list = new TStringList();
list->Add("Hello");
list->Add("World");

for (System::String str : list)
{
    std::wcout << str.c_str() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: "*TStringList does not expose C++ iterators*" - actually, it does: [C++ Iterator Support for Delphi Enumerable Types and Containers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/C%2B%2B_Iterator_Support_for_Delphi_Enumerable_Types_and_Containers)

Comment: @Remy: indeed, it works. Seems this is only described in the docwiki for the Tokyo and Rio versions.

Comment: [it was actually introduced in Berlin](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/using-delphi-containers-from-c)

Comment: @Remy: Thanks, but obviously no useable help yet.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler or IDE do not matter much. What container do you use for your `std::string`s?

Generally, for example, if you use `std::vector` with `std::string`, you can write

```
std::vector<std::string> strings;
// fill them
for(auto& string : strings)
```

This works for a whole lot of other containers and classes.

edit: original text did not reveal anything about `TStringList`, nevertheless, code should be easily transferrable, *if* `TStringList` offers iterators.

Comment: I dont know Delphi, but maybe it is worth mentioning that it makes a difference whether you write `auto&` or `const auto&` (or just `auto`)

Comment: I think `std::vector<string>` should probably be `std::vector<std::string>`?

Comment: OP is using TStringList, which is a container class written in Delphi and used by C++Builder as well, which contains Strings (AnsiString or UnicodeString), not std::string instances. That should answer "what container do you use for std::string": nothing He is using C++Builder's TStringList, as he said.

Comment: In other words: this answer looks nice to those who don't know TStringList (hence the upvotes). It is useless for those who do. **This is not an answer**, since it is based on a completely wrong premiss. **This is not a question about std::vector**, it is about TStringList, and that is not answered in any useful way.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis yep, OP changed his question text aftterwards, there was no way of knowing `TStringList` at that point of time

Comment: @IceFire: I'm sure anyone knowing C++Builder would immediately have known what was meant. That is why I think it is wrong to use the general c++ tag for such questions, since this is specific for C++Builder and has nothing to do with standard C++.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I agree, the `c++` tag is correctly removed now

Comment: @Rigel There are certain conventions after which you write C++ classes. `TStringList`, frankly, is poorly written in terms of modern C++. If it offered iterators to the `begin` and `end` of the set of strings, my solution would indeed work also for `TStringList`

Comment: @IceFire - the vcl/rtl classes used in C++ builder are very different than the "standard" C++ classes. For example they all wave a common ancestor called TObject. Even the strings are different (no #0 at the end of the string). I doubt that "standard" c++ code can operate on them. If you think otherwise please let us know the code.

Comment: @IceFire-TStringList is written in Pascal. I don't exactly know how you can compare it with C++ conventions.

Comment: @Rigel if you can use it in C++, there is most probably some C++ equivalent. If this is the case, the C++ equivalent is written in C++ and should be usable accordingly, but this is just guessing game on my part

Comment: @IceFire Builder is a fusion between C++ and Object Pascal ... parts of code are in C++ and parts in Object Pascal ... The Pascal parts are usually hidden from C++ parts of code but due to this mechanism the classes that are based on Pascal (VCL) are not the same as C++ classes, ...